# JavaScript Output Returning NaN

Tags: javascript, debugging, math, error-handling

I am using App Lab on Code.org, which utilizes JavaScript commands; however, they have their own UI controls. Therefore, the code will contain commands such as onEvent() and setText(), etc. etc. These are all acceptable. I am attempting to make a code for the Spherical Law of Cosines, but my output for the number is printing NaN. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Part of my code is below:

```
onEvent("outputgoScrn","click",function(){
  setScreen("outputScrn");
  setText("output","The distance between these two locations is " + ((Math.acos((Math.cos(a)*(180/Math.PI))*(Math.cos(b)*(180/Math.PI)) + (Math.sin(a)*(180/Math.PI))*(Math.sin(b)*(180/Math.PI)) + (Math.cos(N)*(180/Math.PI))*(180/Math.PI)))) + " miles along the Great Circle.");
});

onEvent("lat1", "change", function() {
  var choice = getProperty("lat1","value");
  if(choice=="N") {
    a = 90 - ((getNumber("lat1deg")+(getNumber("lat1min")/60)));
  }
  else if(choice=="S") {
      a = 90 + (getNumber("lat1deg")+(getNumber("lat1min")/60));
  }
});

onEvent("lat2", "change", function() {
  var choice = getProperty("lat2","value");
  if(choice=="N") {
    b = 90 - ((getNumber("lat1deg")+(getNumber("lat1min")/60)));
  }
  else if(choice=="S") {
      b = 90 + (getNumber("lat2deg")+(getNumber("lat2min")/60));
  }
});


onEvent("lon1", "change", function() {
  var choice = getProperty("lon1","value");
onEvent("lon2","change",function() {
  var choice2 = getProperty("lon2","value");
  if(choice=="E" && choice2=="E") {
    N = (getText(("lon1deg")+(getText("lon1min")/60))) - (getText(("lon2deg")+(getText("lon2min")/60)));
  }
  else if(choice=="W" && choice2=="W") {
    N = getText(("lon1deg")+(getText("lon1min")/60)) - getText(("lon2deg")+(getText("lon2min")/60));
  }
  else if(choice=="W"&&choice2=="E") {
    N = getText(("lon1deg")+(getText("lon1min")/60)) + getText(("lon2deg")+(getText("lon2min")/60));
  }
  else if(choice=="E"&&choice2=="W") {
     N = getText(("lon1deg")+(getText("lon1min")/60)) + getText(("lon2deg")+(getText("lon2min")/60));
  }
});
});
```

Comment: The NaN property represents "Not-a-Number" value. This property indicates that a value is not a legal number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN The calculation somewhere included a non number and the result become not a number.

Comment: That's most likely because your value in `Math.acos()` is greater than 1 or smaller than -1. Log the variable you get for `(Math.cos(a)*(180/Math.PI))*(Math.cos(b)*(180/Math.PI)`
`∀x∊[-1;1],Math.acos(x)=arccos(x)= the unique y∊[0;π]such thatcos(y)=x` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/acos)

Answer (score 0):

NaN stands for "Not a Number". It looks like you are trying to do arithmetic operations with strings. You need to parse your string to number

```
var text = '42px';
var integer = parseInt(text, 10);
// returns 42
```

For more parse functions, you can check below link
https://gomakethings.com/converting-strings-to-numbers-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: That's more like a comment than an answer.